# Typescript error in Jenkins

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, jenkins, typescript

I have the following error in Jenkins ( refers to a path on the disk, each instance of  below can be different and not neccasarily the same as all other instances of )

```
The command "tsc "C:\<path>\shared.editpage-default.ts" "C:\<path>\shared.editpage-editenabled.ts" "C:\<path>\shared.filters.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.common.interfaces.d.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.hide-and-seek.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.domutils.ts" "C:\<path>\jquery.validation.d.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.pagination.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.sorting.ts" "C:\<path>\jquery.d.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.langchange.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.switchbox.ts" "C:\<path>\perfect.validation.ts"" exited with code 9009.
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(847,9): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\<path>\<proj>.csproj]
```

Now, the issue is this.  We have a section in our project file that builds our TypeScript files and creates .js files each time we save the TypeScript file.  This is the section:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files" />
    <Message Text="Executing tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

This all works great locally, but fails in Jenkins because the Jenkins server does not have TypeScript installed.  The thing is that I don't actually need the TypeScript command to be executed on Jenkins because the generated .js files are, as I said, built and created on save anyway, and we check these in.  So there are three options.

1. Install TypeSctipt on the build server.
2. Change the command in the project file so that it only carries out the `<Exec Command="tsc ...` if we are in the configuration is Debug.
3. Change my build scripts to somehow not build the TypeScript files.

Here's what I've tried.

1. I thought I'd try install TypeScript on the build server, but the server is an old Windows Server 2003 machine and when I tried to install TypeScript 0.8.3 on it I got the below error.  So, I installed the latest windows updates on the machine and restarted and re-ran the TypeScript installation and got the same error.

[image]

As for options 2 and 3.

**I think 2 would be the easiest one, though I just don't know the if statement that I must use to only build for the Debug configuration.  If this is the solution please do let me know the command.**

Option 3 I think is probably quite difficult.

Please do make some suggestions.

Comment: VTC. This is really quite localised. Perhaps better on a Jenkins user forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 should be easily doable.  The Exec task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) supports the Condition parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx).  I think what you want looks something like this:

```
<Exec Command="..." Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```